# Handling generic exceptions in specific cases

Tags: c#, exception

I'm trying to move a file from A to B via ftp like this:

```
ftpClient.Rename(sourcePathName, targetPathName);
```

I want to catch and handle all exceptions which occur when the file which has to be moved isn't found. However `Rename` throws the generic exception `FtpCommandException` with value `{"file/directory not found"}`. Unfortunately this exception is thrown in some other cases.

I don't feel that comparing the value of an exception is a clean approach like:

```
if("file/directory not found".equals(exception.value)) ...
```

Comment: If your exceptions need to be handled differently can't you split your rename code out to its own function with it's own try/catch block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should check if the file exists before attempting the rename:

```
if (ftpClient.FileExists(sourcePathName)){
    ftpClient.Rename(sourcePathName, targetPathName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C# 6 onwards, You can use exception filtering

```
try
{
    // your code
}
catch(FtpCommandException ex) 
       when (ex.Value == "file/directory not found")
{
   // do something with this exception
}
```

Pre C#6 your only option was a condition *inside* the catch:

```
try
{
    // your code
}
catch(FtpCommandException ex) 
{
   if(ex.Value == "file/directory not found")
   {
       // do something with this exception
   }
}
```